# php OOP: Doing something in a class's constructor vs calling a private method to do the same thing

Tags: php, oop, constructor

When reading various tutorials I noticed these 2 different approaches and I'm curious about what is happening under the hood.

The first approach does everything in the constructor- everything being setting up variables or in this case calling the class's method to do something. The second approach calls a private method in the constructor to do the same thing. When would one way be preferred over the other? I know micro optimization is evil, but on an academic level is it a little slower to call the private method?

Here is a code example (this is some zf2 code) with the first approach:

```
class LoginForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name = null) {
        // we want to ignore the name passed
        parent::__construct('login-form');

        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'username',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'=> 'text',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'User Name',
            ),
        )); ...
```

VS this:

```
class LoginForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name = null) {
        // we want to ignore the name passed
        parent::__construct('login-form');

        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

        $this->addElements();
    }
    private function addElements() {
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'username',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'=> 'text',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'User Name',
            ),
        )); ...
```

Don't understand why this was flagged. I didn't ask which way was *better* I saw something I didn't completely understand and wanted to hear some possible reasons for *why* one programmer might have done it one way while another did it the other way. The accepted answer was very helpful for me as it also pointed out how one method *may* be evident of possible design issues.

Comment: It's a good practice to keep the constructor simple.

Comment: I think most would favor the second approach for readability. If addElements ever becomes public you have less refactoring.

Comment: So its mostly for readability? That makes sense.

Comment: I agree, the second approach would most probably be preferred. Not just for readability, but also for scalability.

Comment: Is it at all slower- again just asking to fulfill my curiosity. I understand such a minute performance benefit isn't worth creating a non-maintainable mess.

Comment: It might be microscopically slower. With all the optimization they have for interpreters and just in time compilers there could be no difference at all.

Comment: Sure, writing all your code inside the constructor is faster :)

Comment: The second approach can in some cases be a great help when you write your unit tests

Comment: And I disagree with closing this! If you check http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask , see for instance the list of subjective but *constructive* questions, e.g. "invite sharing experiences over opinions", and that is what you can see in the current accepted answer. A great answer about testing I mentioned above could also be given by someone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A private function call in a constructor is a symptom of a code smell. Either the function is very long - which is why you wanted the function call in the first place - or the constructor is doing something which it shouldn't be doing.

In this case `setAttribute` and `addElements` seem to be setting some defaults for the object. There are other ways to achieve this.

Looking at this case in specific you could argue that `LoginForm` should not be a class. Instead you could have a function:

```
function create_login_form() {
    $form = new Form();
    $form->setAttribute("method", "post");
    // etc
    return $form;
}
```

---

Looking more closely at this code: it seems to be some kind wrapper for HTML which is .. questionable. HTML is pretty good at what it does. It's a DSL (Domain Specific Language). `LoginForm` strays too far from the original concepts of the DSL.

If you go one step further you get:

```
function create_login_form() {
    $form = new HTML_Element("form");
    $form->setAttribute("method", "post");
    // etc
    return $form;
}
```

This looks pretty reasonable to me.

Comment: This is more of an opinion than an answer.

Comment: The question is asking for an opinion. You're welcome to flag it as offtopic.

Comment: You may be right about LoginForm not being the best way to go. I haven't used ZF2 in a while but it definitely makes you code in a certain style. The code smell may be a symptom of ZF2 not the OP's code.

Comment: Great answer. might be "opinionated", but you make a good point. Being new to this I haven't seen much code so its a good tip to identify a possibly code smell. And as pbible suggested this is in fact a canonical example of how to implementing Zend\Form in your zf2 application. Starting to understand why many developers say zend is bloated.